# J2ME WebService client

Tags: web-services, java-me, client

I'm trying to create a J2ME webservice client.

While adding the Java webservice, it is showing error as "Failed to generate stubs".

Java Webservice:   http://172.17.1.22/test/webservice.asmx?WSDL
or http://172.17.1.22/test/webservice.asmx

Thanks in advance.